# Extending a luks encrypted partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I'm running Ubuntu inside VMWare with a luks encrypted root partition. I'm following [Resize Encrypted Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions) (from help.ubuntu.com) and am stuck at step 11.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lvresize -L +10G /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
Extending logical volume root to 25.74 GiB
Insufficient free space: 2560 extents needed, but only 4 available
```

`fdisk -l` shows the additional space available on the physical drive, I'm just not sure on what command is holding me back from using lvresize.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3916 cylinders, total 62914560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000f36ef

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758    41940991    20719617    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760    41940991    20719616   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/crypt1: 21.2 GB, 21214789632 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2579 cylinders, total 41435136 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/crypt1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 16.9 GB, 16903045120 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2055 cylinders, total 33013760 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 4290 MB, 4290772992 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 521 cylinders, total 8380416 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Info about my physical Volume

```
lvm> pvdisplay --- Physical volume --- PV Name /dev/dm-0 VG Name ubuntu-vg PV Size 19.76 GiB / not usable 3.81 MiB Allocatable yes PE Size 4.00 MiB Total PE 5057 Free PE 4 Allocated PE 5053 PV UUID b6DksK-NYal-Wvai-0iUc-ku1J-PwZy-wWZtLB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pvdisplay` to see how much space is available on your physical volumes that are set up in LVM. You may need to add space to that first.

`pvdisplay` shows what devices like /dev/sda1, etc are set up to be managed by LVM.

`vgdisplay` shows info about the volume groups that are made up of the different physical volumes. A volume group can span over several physical volumes.

`lvdisplay` show info about the logical volumes in the volume groups.

To extend a logical volume, there needs to be available space/extents in the volume group. To expand a volume group, there needs to be space on the physical volumes the volume group is on. You can add physical volumes and expand onto those.

Comment: vgdisplay will tell you about the volume groups. Do you have spare space on some device like /dev/sda5? Looks like you'll have to add a new physical volume to the volume group and then extend the logical volume once the volume-group has more space.

Comment: @JosephSantaniello please edit your answer with your comment to make the answer complete - comments will eventually be deleted.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more complete as per suggestion.